# Jenkins - publish over FTP - clear remote - StackOverflowError

Tags: jenkins, ftp, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up auto deploy of the application to the server over FTP. I'm using Publish over FTP plugin.

Uploading files works as expected but if I select option "Clean remore" I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:920)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:785)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateMListParsing(FTPClient.java:3437)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.mlistDir(FTPClient.java:2543)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.mlistDir(FTPClient.java:2530)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ftp.BapFtpClient.delete(BapFtpClient.java:94)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ftp.BapFtpClient.delete(BapFtpClient.java:115)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ftp.BapFtpClient.delete(BapFtpClient.java:95)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ftp.BapFtpClient.delete(BapFtpClient.java:115)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ftp.BapFtpClient.delete(BapFtpClient.java:95)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ftp.BapFtpClient.delete(BapFtpClient.java:115)
```

Does anybody know how to make it works?

Comment: Do you have privileges to delete things on remote?

Comment: Yes, I do. I already tested credentials I'm using in Jenkins configuration and I'm able to remove files.